# Product Catalog sync not working with Hybris CompositeCronjob

Tags: cron, synchronization, jobs, sap-commerce-cloud

With **CompositeCronjob**, I want **PRODUCT SYNC** and **FULL SOLR Index** jobs to run, respectively.
For this, I ran the **PRODUCT SYNC** job once and added the resulting cronjob code to the **CompositeCronjob as an Entry**.
Likewise, I ran the **FULL Solr Index** job and added the resulting cronjob code to the **CompositeCronjob as an Entry**.
I would run the CompositeCronjob, no ERROR. But PRODUCT SYNC **only worked for 1-2 seconds** and took SUCCES and went to the next step Solr Index step.
But PRODUCT SYNC didn't actually do anything for 1-2 seconds. **It didn't synchronize any products**. How can I solve this problem? It does not give an error, but it does not synchronize the products.

I am using Hybris version **19.05**

I am very grateful in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please Validate Composite cronjob entries are correct or not.

Example as follows :

```
   INSERT_UPDATE CompositeEntry;code[unique=true]                                    ;executableCronJob(code)
                            ;updateComposite-$storeUidStaticIndexB2C-jobEntry     ;staticContentUpdate-$storeUidStaticIndexB2C-cronJob
                            ;updateIndex-$storeUidStaticIndexB2C-jobEntry         ;update-$storeUidStaticIndexB2C-cronJob


INSERT_UPDATE CompositeCronJob;code[unique=true]                                                ;job(code)               ;sessionLanguage(isocode);compositeEntries(code);nodeId[default=0]
                              ;compositeStaticContentUpdate-$storeUidStaticIndexB2C-cronJob     ;compositeJobPerformable ;en                      ;updateComposite-$storeUidStaticIndexB2C-jobEntry,updateIndex-$storeUidStaticIndexB2C-jobEntry
```

Comment: Hello there,

I tried this way, but Product SYNC only works for 1 second and the products still do not SYNC.

Comment: could you please check the logs,I hope the independent products sync job is working properly.

Comment: There is no problem with the logs.
sync rabiaProductCatalog:Staged->Online : 00002BC0 - FINISHED - SUCCESS
last start time
Jun 28, 2021 1:31:00 PM
last time
Jun 28, 2021 1:31:01 PM

It works for 1 second and it becomes Success. But the products do not Sync.

Comment: Please check by which user are you trying to run the composite corn job?

Comment: I am running it as admin user.